# Rails Controller Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am trying to display a list of users on a page based on an attribute of the current user. If the current user has its instance variable called :position as "High School" list all the users with the :position "College" (and vice versa). I know I do this in the controller with an if else statement, but I cant figure out what the query call should be. Right now I have:

```
if current_user.position= "High School"
  @user = User.all
else
  @user= User.all
```

As a template. However, I need to switch the @user= statements, but I cant figure out how to restrict it. Any help? Thanks!

```
<% @quizzes.each do |quiz| %>
  <tr>
    <td><h6><%= quiz.userName%></h6></td>
    <td><h6><%= quiz.q1 %></h6></td>
    <td><% for q in quiz.q2 %>
      <% if q != nil %>
        <h6><%= q  %></h6>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <td><h6><%= quiz.q3 %></h6></td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3:

```
if current_user.position == "High School"
   @user = User.where(:position => "College")
else
   @user = User.where(:position => "High School")
end
```

Rails 2:

```
if current_user.position == "High School"
  @user = User.find_all_by_position("College")
else
  @user = User.find_all_by_position("High School")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use `scope` in model class.

Define scopes in User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  scope :college,    where(position: 'College')
  scope :highschool, where(position: 'High School')
end
```

and in your controller,

```
if current_user.position == "High School"
  @users = User.college
else
  @users = User.highschool
end
```

Hope it would be help.

Comment: If you added the scopes, and want to remove the if statement, you could do: `@users = User.send current_user.position`

Comment: Okay I realized that I am actually laying out my view like an idiot so maybe you can help me one more time. My view lays out a table of quizzes.each and a quiz belongs to a user. So by updating user, it has no affect on the quizzes that are being displayed. How can I modify the @quizzes variable in the user controller so it only finds quizzes that belongs to users of the opposite varialbe? I'll add the table to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
if current_user.position == "High School"
   @users = User.where(:position => "College")
else
   @users = User.where(:position => "High School")
end
```